# what does the following program print?

Tags: c

```
main()
{
char s[] = "abcdef", *p;
for (p = &s[5]; p >= s; p--) --p*;
puts(s);
return 0;
}
```

The compiler says there is a problem with --p* (expected an expression)?????

Comment: I suspect the error is because one line is missing something (at the end) that the other lines have... or the `--*p` in the code above is not as you have locally. The "error message" is confusing/incorrect for the posted code.

Comment: @user663936. There's little point changing the code if you question still states the compiler has a problem with the bit you modified. You should either change the code back or change the rest of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there *is* a problem with `--p*`, it's not valid C, hence the program prints nothing. You're also missing a semi-colon from the end of your `char s[] ...` line.

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    char s[] = "abcdef", *p;
    for (p = &s[5]; p >= s; p--) --*p;
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

which prints:

```
`abcde
```

(assuming you're running in an ASCII environment of course).

And, *any* book that declares `main` as:

```
main()
```

instead of one of the two canonical forms, should be tossed out.

One other thing to watch out for, the standard doesn't mandate that pointer aritmetic will work unless both pointers point within the object or one beyond the end. So comparing the final value of `p` (which is `&(s[-1])`) against `s` is not guaranteed to work. A better solution is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    char s[] = "abcdef", *p;
    for (p = s; *p != 0; p++) --*p;
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The relevant section of C99 is `6.5.6/8`:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand.
>
> ...
>
> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

Comment: @user663936 : Throw that book in a dustbin.

Comment: @user: the loop modifies the string in place

Comment: @user663936: yes it does have an effect, it decrements the characters in the string.

Comment: OK, i got it! the problem was in --*p, since --p* is invalid expression in C. So instead of characters it uses ASCII integer and decrements it.

Answer (score 4):

`--p*` doesn't make any sense .

Probably you meant `--*p` or `--p`?
Your code prints `` `abcde `` when the underlying representation is ASCII. BTW C99 mandates the return type of `main()` to be `int` in a hosted environment.

Comment: And then, I would guess, "'abcde", though C does not actually say what `'a'-1` is. (That ' should be a backquote, but I don't know how to escape formatting on stackoverflow.)

Comment: `--(*p)`, actually, since `--*p` would decrement `p` and produce `*p` from the result.

Comment: @geekosaur : `--*p` is equivalent to `--(*p)`

Comment: @geekosaur: aren't you confusing with `*--p`?

Comment: @geekosaur: No postfix operators? What are `i++;` and `i--` then?

Comment: yes.  0437 here, past bedtime.  "step away from the keyboard..."

Comment: @geekosaur: Have a verbena infusion and sleep well then :-)

Answer (score 3):

- You're missing a `;` at line 3, and,
- You probably want

  ```
  --p
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  --p*
  ```

The program then prints `abcdef`.

Here is an [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/XTNHt).

Answer (score 1):

there's a missing semicolon... i can see it clearly!